# ADF Expression function "IF" with more than 2 conditions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I Have question about Azure Data Factory Expression for function IF

in SQL we can create using

```
CASE WHEN 'A' Then 1
     when  'B' then 2
     when 'C' then 3
else 100
```

is this correct expression to IF?

```
@if(equals(variables('varInput'), 'a'), 'Ax', 
if(equals(variables('varInput'), 'b'), 'Bx', 'C'))
```

how to us "IF" function for more than 2 or we can use another Function like "Or"?

this is the expression that i built

```
@if(equals(formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'MMdd'),'0101'), concat('PRODUCT/','daily/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(getPastTime(1,'Year'),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyy'),'/','12'),'/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(getPastTime(1,'Day'),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyyMMdd')), if(equals(formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'dd'),'01'), concat('PRODUCT/','daily/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(getPastTime(1,'Month'),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(getPastTime(1,'Day'),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyyMMdd')),concat('PRODUCT/','daily/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(getPastTime(1,'Day'),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyyMMdd')))
```

I want to create folder base on this case

1. If today's date is 2023-01-01 then  folder name path will be PRODUCT/2022/12/20221231
2. if today's date is 2023-02-01  then folder name path will be PRODUCT/2023/01/20230131
3. if todays date is 2023-03-02 then folder name path will be PRODUCT/2023/03/20230301

but expression IF doest support more than 2 arguments

Comment: No, you need to explicitly 'if' the 'c' too, and the final 'then' would be 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IF doesn't support more than 2 arguments.

In order to give multiple conditions, you can use the nested if expression i.e.  if expression inside another if .

I used the same expression what you have tried and got error.

This error is because, closing paranthesis `)` are misplaced in that expression. I have highlighted that in the below image.

[image]

**Corrected expression** :

You can use the below expression for your requirement.

```
@if(equals(formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'MMdd'),'0101'), concat('PRODUCT/','daily/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(getPastTime(1,'Year'),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyy'),'/','12','/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(getPastTime(1,'Day'),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyyMMdd')), if(equals(formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'dd'),'01'), concat('PRODUCT/','daily/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(getPastTime(1,'Month'),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(getPastTime(1,'Day'),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyyMMdd')),concat('PRODUCT/','daily/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(getPastTime(1,'Day'),'SE Asia Standard Time'),'yyyyMMdd'))))
```

Comment: looks good, but how to test it to make sure 0101 works ? do we need to wait next year?

Comment: You can test by storing date in a variable and by passing it in that expression instead of giving utcnow(). But getPastTime() function is based on the current date.